# Let A and B be independent random events, $p(A$), $p(B)$ $\in(0,1)$. Which formula is not true?

Tags: probability

Let A and B be independent random events, $p(A$), $p(B)$ $\in(0,1)$. Which formula is not true?
$$p(A\cap B)=0$$
$$p(A\cup B)=p(A)+p(B)-p(A)p(B)$$
$$p(A/B)=p(A)$$
$$p(A\cap B) = p(B)p(A)$$
$$p(B/A)=p(B)$$

So $p(A\cap B) = p(B)p(A)$ is true because of independent rule.

$p(A/B)=p(A)$ and $p(B/A)=p(B)$ also true, they are independent  so if we exclude other probability it will leave them by themselves.

$p(A\cap B)=0$ true, no joint elements.

This leaves me with $p(A\cup B)=p(A)+p(B)-p(A)p(B)$, this one gotta be false right? I can't come up with any logic for it.

Comment: $p(A\cap B)=0$ cannot be true, it's usual mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p(A\cap B)=p(A)p(B) >0$ so $p(A\cap B)=0$ is false.

It is always true that $p(A\cup B)=p(A)+p(B)-p(A\cap B)$. When you have independence this becomes $p(A\cup B)=p(A)+p(B)-p(A)p(B)$.